# Error saving backbone model: Uncaught Error: A "url" property or function must be specified

Tags: backbone.js

I'm new to backbone and trying to figure out why a simple "save" of a model in an app doesn't work. I have a model for my login window that I'm trying to save. The model is initialized as follows:

```
window.myapp.login = new window.myapp.Models.Login();
window.myapp.signinBox = new window.myapp.Views.Signin({model: window.myapp.login});
window.myapp.signinBox.render();
```

now in signinBox I listen to various events, and call this.model.get and this.model.set - everything works fine.
However when I try to call

```
this.model.save();
```

I get: Uncaught Error: A "url" property or function must be specified

The model class looks like:

```
window.myapp.Models.Login = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults:{
        modelType:'login',
        urlRoot:'/rest/login',
        password: "",
        rememberMe: false,
        isAuthenticated: false
    }
})
```

Any idea what my be wrong here?

One thing I notices (as I said I'm a newbie and this may be trivial) is that I don't see urlRoot under this.model, but rather under this.model.attributes. Is this supposed to be this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The defaults hash (or function) is used to specify the default attributes for your model attributes. But the [urlRoot](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-urlRoot) is a separate property of the `Backbone.Model` which need to be set the the root level:

```
window.myapp.Models.Login = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: '/rest/login',
    defaults:{
        modelType:'login',       
        password: "",
        rememberMe: false,
        isAuthenticated: false
    }
})
```